# GitLab pipeline rules:exists with more than 10000 files in repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am using a template for my CI/CD on GitLab. I want to enable some jobs only for repositories with specific files. I try to use *rules:exists*:

```
rules:
  - exists:
      - Src/*/ApiTests/*.json
```

But my repositories contain more than 10000 files and GitLab has a restriction:

> For performance reasons, GitLab matches a maximum of 10,000 exists patterns or file paths. After the 10,000th check, rules with patterned globs always match. In other words, the exists rule always assumes a match in projects with more than 10,000 files.

I can make checks on before_script, but I want to hide this job from the pipeline.

Currently running Gitlab-EE 13.3.9

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered yourself, I see as only workaround to do the check in the `before_script` and set a variable that you will check in the `rules` + `if`.

Comment: `rules` are evaluated when the pipelines is created, so I don't think the workaround you mention would work.

Comment: Oh, thanks, so everything should be done in the script section.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers. I decided to add variable to project and use 'only:variables'